# kubernetes nginx ingress confusion

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ingress-nginx

I'm trying to get a feel for the Kubernetes Nginx ingress controller. Trying to deploy it to an AKS cluster, however I can't figure out the following. According to [Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli)

`To control image versions, you'll want to import them into your own Azure Container Registry. The NGINX ingress controller Helm chart relies on three container images. Use az acr import to import those images into your ACR.`

So, I've pulled, tagged and pushed the controller, patch and default backend images to ACR.

Next, did `helm show values ingress/nginx/ingress-nginx > values.yaml` and created a new `.yaml` to reference it a installation time (so that it can grab the images from ACR rather than the default repo).

However, after install I'm surprised to find only 1 pod related to nginx

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-764784f688-qbbq8      1/1     Running   0          49m
```

I've even tried to install it with the defaults without providing my own `.yaml` with `-f foo.yaml` like this:

```
 helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx   --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx   --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

But still only 1 pod:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-6bf7bc7f94-ml4js   1/1     Running   0          55s
```

Per my understanding this is what gets created:
[image: controller]

[image: patch]

[image: default]

What am I missing please ?

Comment: I think you should open a git issue in the helm charts repo.

Comment: How do you check ? `kubectl get po -A | grep nginx` ?

Answer (score 0):

ingress-nginx-controller-6bf7bc7f94-ml4js looks like a pod. Pods are not containers but they can contain containers. Why don't you describe it and see what containers it contains.

Comment: It shows only the `controller` container, so the pod contains just one container. The other 2 are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the line that said there should be two replicas?

> For added redundancy, two replicas of the NGINX ingress controllers are deployed with the `--set controller.replicaCount` parameter. To fully benefit from running replicas of the ingress controller, make sure there's more than one node in your AKS cluster.